# Procedure expects parameter which was not supplied in ASP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a dropdownlist that is populated with semesters.  When the semester selection is changed, I want to populate another dropdownlist with courses available for that semester based on the semesterID.  I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that gets courses based on the semesterId parameter.  The semester list is populated just fine, but when I select a semester, I get an error while using the SP to get the courses.  The error says `Procedure or function 'GetCourses' expects parameter '@semesterId', which was not supplied.`  even though I supply the value for @semesterId before I open the connection.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
                PopulateSemesterList();
        }

        private void PopulateSemesterList()
        {
            string connstring;
            connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetSemesters", conn);
            conn.Open();

            DDSemesters.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DDSemesters.DataTextField = "semesterName";
            DDSemesters.DataValueField = "semesterId";
            this.DataBind();

            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();

            DDSemesters.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Semester", "0"));
            DDSemesters.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        protected void DDSemesters_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList DDSemesters = sender as DropDownList;

            int selectedSemester = Convert.ToInt32(DDSemesters.SelectedItem.Value);

            string connstring;
            connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetCourses", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@semesterId", selectedSemester));

            conn.Open();

            DDCourses.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DDCourses.DataTextField = "courseName";
            DDCourses.DataValueField = "courseId";
            this.DataBind();

            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();

            DDCourses.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Course", "0"));
            DDCourses.SelectedIndex = 0;
            DDCourses.Visible = true;
            CoursesLbl.Visible = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell your `CommandType` is the default, `Text`, which causes the `CommandText` to be interpreted as an SQL query instead of just a stored procedure name.

You'll want to set it to `StoredProcedure` instead:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Alternatively you could make your command a full SQL query that properly passes the parameters to the stored procedure.